# ImportXML in googlesheet with the delayed display

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to update the value in the web to my google sheet. But, in the this website, it loaded an old cache in 0.5s before loading the right. So when I use the function

```
=IMPORTXML("https://wm.vinacapital.com/vi/investment-solutions/onshore-funds/vesaf/","//*[@id='fundnavup']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]")
```

It will return old value instead of right value.

How can I load a right value. (I can use apps scripts)